# git: fetch --recurse-submodules does fetching twice

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have in git a superproject and a few submodules. After executing the command

`git fetch --all --recurse-submodules`

at the superproject, all the submodules will be fetched twice.
Do you know why?

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

Follow the relevant bug report here: https://public-inbox.org/git/CAN8jHOgwVF5g=jM_KYT0Oh+j+Lk3qvdyA4zNRbzf8e1Xp5WAUw@mail.gmail.com/

The patch has been merged into master and this problem should be fixed in the upcoming git release (**v2.37+**, ~June 2022), as stated in the release notes for [v2.37.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ab336e8f1c8009c8b1aab8deb592148e69217085/Documentation/RelNotes/2.37.0.txt#L204).

For the technical details, you may be interested to view the relevant patch of the fix, found [on github](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa61b7703e7f19f172af3311af8dc04581ecdf69).